# Get to get data from arrayList in another class?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, getter-setter

```
  /**
 * 5 points
 *
 * You will write a method that converts a JSON Object into a Song object. It should assume that the input is in the format:
 * {"title":"Lose Yourself", "artist":"Eminem", "ratings":[5,5,4,5], "youtubeID":"xFYQQPAOz7Y"}
 *
 * @param jsonSong  A song in JSON format
 * @return A Song object with the data from the JSON Value
 */
public static Song jsonToSong(JsonObject jsonSong){
    String title =jsonSong.get("title").asString();
    String YoutubeID =jsonSong.get("youtubeID").asString();
    String artist =jsonSong.get("artist").asString();



    ArrayList<Integer> ratings = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Song object = new Song(YoutubeID,title,artist,ratings);
    object.setTitle(title);
    object.setArtist(artist);
    object.setRatings(ratings);
    object.setYoutubeID(YoutubeID);


    return object;
```

I've written this code which converts a JsonObject into a type Song Object, everything converts except for the arraylist (ratings).

How do I retrieve it's data correctly using getter and setter methods?

My getter setter methods are:

```
 public ArrayList<Integer> getRatings(){
    return ratings;
}

public void setRatings(ArrayList<Integer> ratings){
    this.ratings = ratings;
}
```

The constructor:

```
   // Constructor
public Song(String youtubeID, String title, String artist, ArrayList<Integer> ratings){
    this.youtubeID = youtubeID;
    this.title = title;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.ratings = ratings;
}
```

Over here you can see that everything converts except for rating when ran through the grader

```
    Incorrect on input: {"title":"Comfortably Numb","artist":"Pink Floyd","ratings":[5,4,5,5],"youtubeID":"_FrOQC-zEog"}
Expected output : {title:Comfortably Numb, artist:Pink Floyd, ratings:[5, 4, 5, 5], youtubeID:_FrOQC-zEog}
Your output     : {title:Comfortably Numb, artist:Pink Floyd, ratings:[], youtubeID:_FrOQC-zEog}
Score: 0
```

Comment: What's the point of passing the same data into your constructor and setters? And what is your question exactly?

Comment: I need to use the data from arraylist ratings which could look something like this [5,6,5] to put into the SongObject ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     ArrayList<Integer> ratings = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
            JsonValue collect = jsonSong.get("ratings"); 
            JsonArray rate = collect.asArray();
            for(int i=0; i<rate.size(); i++){
                ratings.add(rate.get(i).asInt());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what Json library that you use, but I guess this JsonObject has something like method getJsonArray(), you can try to use it toget an object with type JsonArray, then iterate it and get what you want.

Or something like this

```
        JSONArray ratings= (JSONArray) jsonSong.get("ratings");
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = ratings.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```